# use info from one function to another

Tags: javascript

I am trying retrieve a value from one function and would like to use that value in another function. This function returns a city, state and I present that on screen.

```
<script>
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
$("#address").html(response.city + ", " + response.region);
}, "jsonp");
</script>

<div id="address"></div>
```

But I would like to use the city value for another piece of JS that uses city values to return current weather. That code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
loadWeather('Baltimore',''); //@params location, woeid
});
```

'Baltimore' is currently hard-coded in the JS and I would like the returned city value from above to be placed in the weather function. The weather function only seems to accept the city as a string and not a code snippet like the answers below have presented. Can I make the resulting city into a variable that is then passed to the weather function?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: sorry, I edited my query to include my problem. thanks

Comment: When are the two above snippets of code likely to run?

Comment: the weather function only seems to accept the string of the city and not the code that presented in the answers below. Can I make the city result a string variable thats used in the lower function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider calling your `loadWeather()` function within the callback function of your `get()` AJAX call :

```
<script>
    $(function(){
         // Get your city information
         $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
              // At this point you have a response, so use it
              $("#address").html(response.city + ", " + response.region);
              // Pass the city to your loadWeather function
              loadWeather(response.city,''); 
         }, "jsonp");
    });
</script>
```

The order in which you call these functions is important as your `loadWeather()` function clearly depends on you retreiving a value from your `get()` call (as you actually need the city to load the weather for).

Comment: the loadWeather function seems to only accept the city value as a string like 'Baltimore'.. its breaking with the code snippet you presented. any thoughts?

Comment: The [API](http://ipinfo.io/) of the service that you provided looks as though the `response.city` value should be correct if you are looking for the city name. Have you tried placing a `debugger;` within your callback to see what your response looks like?

Comment: ah ok. thanks.. my code just doesnt seem to like that I took the 2 separate functions and made them 1.. you can see my entire code here: codepen.io/anon/pen/VaOBZx   even when I hard code the city back into the snippet you provided, it breaks.

Comment: Try wrapping your function calls within your `$(document).ready(){...});` block as seen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONYYaB).

Comment: ok thanks, in your example, the weather function still isnt functioning

Comment: It appears to be. My current location displays 75° whereas if I replace `response.city` with "Baltimore", it displays 58°

Comment: nvm, it is working, there just isnt info for my city. thanks for your help!

Comment: thanks again for your help.. when I change the variable from city to postal code, it works like a charm for anywhere. much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a value before you have that value. Call the other function when you have the value you need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#address").html(response.city + ", " + response.region);
    loadWeather(response.city,''); //@params location, woeid
  }, "jsonp");
});
```

Comment: the loadWeather function seems to only accept the city value as a string like 'Baltimore'.. its breaking with the code snippet you presented. any thoughts?

Comment: @scott.schaffer — The service returns a string — http://jsbin.com/civenu/1/edit?html,js,console gives me London, string as the output — so perhaps you are just in an unsupported location.

Comment: ah ok. thanks.. my code just doesnt seem to like that I took the 2 separate functions and made them 1.. you can see my entire code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaOBZx  even when I hard code the city back into the snippet you provided, it breaks.

Comment: @scott.schaffer — Or you might just be mixing HTTP and HTTPS: https://www.evernote.com/l/AANUFDgc-RJD5KZDXqeIiq1jQ2uzSqq7Td8

Answer (score 1):

Calling `loadWeather` within your `jQuery.get()` callback will give `loadWeather` access to the data in `response`, but doesn't really answer your original question: how do you use info from one function in another? The simplest solution would be to pull things apart into separate functions, so you could use the output of one function as an argument of the other:

```js
loadWeather(getLocationFromIp());
```

That won't work here, though, since the operation to get location data is *asynchronous* -- there's no way to be sure when you'll get the data you need from the server. That's why you used a callback function in the first place.

#### Sharing Asynchronous Data with Promises

You can get around this, while still keeping the weather update and location update functions separated, by [using jQuery's deferred/promise features](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jqxhr-object). This also gives you a chance to handle the location request to ipinfo.io failing.

And while we're at it, let's handle cases (like mine) where ipinfo.io returns `''` for city and region. In that case, falling back to latitude & longitude will still give the simpleWeather plugin what it needs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  getLocationFromIp()
    .done(function(response) {
      var has_city = (response.city && response.region);
      var location = has_city ? (response.city + ', ' + response.region) : response.loc;
      $('#address').html(location);
      loadWeather(location);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert('Error getting location info. Try reloading in a moment.');
    });
});

function getLocationFromIp() {
  return $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io');
}
```

Okay, but what's the point of using promises and a separate `getLocationFromIp` function? Except for the failure message (which simpleWeather could handle better than `alert()`), you could do all that in the original `$.get()` callback.

#### Reusing Data with Caching

The benefit of breaking things into smaller, independent pieces appears when you move a little beyond what your pen is currently doing. Now you can use other methods of passing one function's data to another to do things like update the weather without having to re-request location data from ipinfo.io.

I'm guessing, from the location search field and use of Google Maps autocomplete, that you have more in mind for this code. So let's go ahead and expand things a little. For an example, we'll cache (store) the user's detected location with `jQuery.data()` then refresh the weather every 10 minutes using that information:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  getLocationFromIp()
    .done(function(response) {
      var has_city = (response.city && response.region);
      var location = has_city ? (response.city + ', ' + response.region) : response.loc;
      $('#address')
        .html(location)
        .data('location', location);
      loadWeather(location);
      // update every 10 min
      setInterval(loadWeather, 60000);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      // Updating simpleWeather with an invalid location triggers the plugin's error message:
      loadWeather('0');
    });
});

function getLocationFromIp() {
  return $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io');
}

function loadWeather(location) {
  // if no location argument passed, use cached location
  var loc = location || $('#address').data('location');

  $.simpleWeather({
    location: loc,
    // more simpleWeather config...
  });
}
```

You can see the above approach in full here: http://codepen.io/adammessinger/pen/VaOJdq

#### Sharing Data Among Functions with Encapsulation

If you wanted to get a bit fancier, you could also cache and reuse the location info without touching the DOM by leveraging the Revealing Module Pattern and closure.

All the functions in that module would have access to the current location data. You could expose some or all of them as public methods for manipulating the state of your weather widget. For example, updating the weather info to match whatever location the user types into `input#searchTextField` with `WeatherWidget.updateLocation(input.value)` or turning timed refresh of the weather data on and off when the user toggles a checkbox.

This bundling of data together with relevant functions is a form of *encapsulation,* a facet of object-oriented programming. But I'm getting far from the original question, so I'll leave it at that.